# Is there a common practice for dynamically generate controls created by Visual Studio Designer?

Tags: c#, user-controls, dynamically-generated

I am developing an inventory management program. Through the program, administrators can add items to the inventory. Since this is a fundamental feature of the program, it is displayed in the main `Form` and is not hidden within the menu.

Non-Administrator users should not be able to see this feature. The easiest option for hiding it is to set its `Visible` property to `false`. The problem with this approach is that I load the feature to memory, while I do not need it at all. I am looking for a creative solution. Some will say that this is premature micro-optimization (which is [the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), as we all know), but for me, it is more a matter of writing correct code, not hacks.

So I have created a method that dynamically generates the feature, with all its components, and it is invoked if an administrator is logged in. While this approach fixes the memory issue, it does not allow me to use the Visual Studio designer, and I have to write every line of the feature design.

The solution I thought of was to extract the feature into a `UserControl`, so it could be designed through the designer. The method mentioned before instantiates it and adds it to the `Form`. I am uncomfortable with this solution since it uses a `UserControl` for a different purpose than its original: [creating reusable controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379501/1925272).

Besides, using a `UserControl` this conflicts with my program architecture. Changing the architecture in a critical way is not practical now, especially that the real problem is the misuse of the `UserControl` and not the architecture.

Each `Form` has its own namespace. For example, the main `Form` namespace is `Main`. The `Form` is built using [*MVP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), so each of these namespaces has a `Model`, `View`, and `Presenter` classes. Each `Form` has a sub-namespace for `UserControl`s. So `Main.UserControls` will contain the `UserControl`s that were created especially for `Main` to use. `UserControl`s that are shared by several `Form`s are in a different namespace, higher in the namespaces hierarchy.

Because of the `UserControl` definition, the `Main.UserControls` namespace is expected to contain small, useful `Control`s (such as a `ComboBox` with predefined values), rather than an entire program feature with a connection to the database. Just by looking at the code, another programmer may find it difficult to understand why this `UserControl` is there.

Additionally, since this `UserControl` contains a connection to the database, it requires the use of *MVP*. Suddenly there are two, not-`UserControl`, unexpected, extra classes in `Main.UserControls`.

Is there a better, common solution for dynamically?

---

**Note:**
I am not looking for opinions, just asking if there is a well known common practice.

Comment: Nope, there is are no practices. In fact, that requirement is quite exotic. E.g. there is single control - `PropertyGrid` - as alternative to multiple dialogs.

Comment: @Sinatr - Could you please elaborate in an answer?

Comment: I would answer if I would understand the problem. The question is too broadly worded and contain many parts which can be answered individually. Again, `PropertyGrid` can replace settings form, it's dynamic and very flexible. But database? MVP? Concerns like "another programmer may find it difficult to understand" only adding uncertainty. It's not possible to answer unless you clarify better your requirements, show what you have now and why it doesn't work for you (though that's rather [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question).

Comment: My goal is to write good code. Good code is often measured by the ability of another programmer to understand it. Since the program has a very clear architecture,  breaking it can cause confusion for another programmer, which is an indication of bad code.

Comment: I briefly explained the architecture. The code uses the database to insert items into the inventory. To separate the visual design logic and the data logic, I use MVP. Therefore, each form in the program is composed of at least three classes, not one.

Comment: Because `UserControl`s should be simple, my architecture assumes they are made up of one class, so all `UserControl`s are under one namespace. Because my solution uses a complex `UserControl` and uses the database, I have to use MVP - hence, three classes - to represent the `UserControl`, which creates a mess within the namespace. @Sinatr